# Working with Embeddable in FluentNHibernate?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I'm looking for any how to or documentation about use of `Embeddable` with FluentNHibernate exactly with in the Hibernate. Does has any way to works with Embeddable in FluentNHibernate, if not has what's the best way to simulate this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found some solution. It's very simple like `Embeddable` of JPA/Hibernate.

Found here: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#components

Then I did.

```
public class Cliente {

        public virtual long id                          { set; get; }
        public virtual long codigo                      { set; get; }
        public virtual String nome                      { set; get; }
        public virtual String sexo                      { set; get; }
        public virtual String cpf                       { set; get; }
        public virtual String rg                        { set; get; }
        public virtual DateTime dtNascimento            { set; get; }
        public virtual Endereco endereco                { set; get; } //Embeddable

        public Cliente() { }
    }



public class Endereco {

        public  String endereco;
        public  String numero;
        public  String bairro;
        public  String complemento;
        public  String cidade;
        public  String cep;
        public  EstadosBrasil uf;

        public Endereco() {            
        }
    }
```

**Mapping**

```
public class ClienteMap : ClassMap<Cliente> {
        public ClienteMap() {
            Table("CLIENTE");
            Id(c => c.id).GeneratedBy.Native();
            Map(c => c.codigo);
            Map(c => c.nome);
            Map(c => c.sexo).Length(2);
            Map(c => c.cpf);
            Map(c => c.rg);
            Map(c => c.dtNascimento).CustomType<DateTime>();
            //embeddable
            Component(c => c.endereco, e => {
                                            e.Map(c => c.endereco);
                                            e.Map(c => c.numero).CustomType<int>();
                                            e.Map(c => c.bairro);
                                            e.Map(c => c.complemento);
                                            e.Map(c => c.cidade);
                                            e.Map(c => c.cep);
                                            e.Map(c => c.uf).CustomType<GenericEnumMapper<EstadosBrasil>>();
                                            });

        }
    }
```